# Inverse matrix as a sum of matrix powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, jordan-normal-form

I have matrix $ A\in \mathbb{C}^{n x n}$ and $A$ is invertible.

How can I show that coefficients $c_0,...,c_{n-1}$ exist :

$A^{-1} = c_0I+c_1A+...+c_{n-1}A^{n-1}$

I tried to solve it first by multiplying the equation above with $A$ which gives:

$I = c_0A + c_1A^2 + ... +c_{n-1}A^n$

And I continued then by knowing that every square matrix can be written with Jordan canonical form ($A = VJ_aV^-1$):

$I = c_0VJ_aV^{-1} + c_1VJ_a^2V^{-1}+...+c_{n-1}VJ_a^nV^{-1}$

Which can be written in form:

$I = V(c_0J_a+c_1J_a^2+....+c_{n-1}J_a^n)V^{-1}$

After this point my task is to show that the identity matrix can be presented with sum of coefficients and Jordan canonical forms, but I don't have any idea how to do that or even if my approach to this problem is right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial is $\det(A)$ and by the Cayely-Hamilton theorem it annihilates $A$...